# how to append a xml file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i am adding tracing for audit purposes of a simple process i have built as an .exe and set in the scheduler to run every 10 minutes. i want to have the application output the results into an xml file.

if the file exists then open and append data to it, if it does not exist i want to create a new xml file that will be persisted and used on next run.

here is my code now, what do i need to add, how do i open the xml file (on c:/file.xml) and use it to append nodes to?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
    doc.AppendChild(dec);// Create the root element

    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("STATS");
    doc.AppendChild(root);

    XmlElement urlNode = doc.CreateElement("keepalive");
    urlNode.SetAttribute("runTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());

    try
    {
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://proxy.ml.com:8083/");
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        w.Proxy = wp;

        if (w.DownloadString("http://wwww.example.com") != "")
            urlNode.SetAttribute("result", "UP");
        else
            urlNode.SetAttribute("result", "DOWN");
    }
    catch
    {
        urlNode.SetAttribute("result", "DOWN");
    }
    finally
    {
        root.AppendChild(urlNode);
        doc.Save("c:/keepAlive.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have most of your solution - you're creating nodes appendign them and saving. If how to read from a file is really the problem I suggest you go look at the constructor overloads for XmlDocument on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append an XML file - you'll have to load the file in memory , modify/add/etc, and then write it to disk.

**EDIT :**

Well, for loading a file you would use :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); // create an xml document object.
if(System.IO.File.Exists("yourXMLFile.xml")
    xmlDoc.Load("yourXMLFile.xml");// load from file
else{
   // create the structure of your xml document
   XmlElement root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("STATS");
   xmlDoc.AppendChild(root);
}
```

and then start adding the keepalive stuff.

I would actually go a bit further and not mess around with xml. I'd create a class that contains everything I need and just serialize and deserialize it.

**Like this:**

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Stats{
  public Stats(){}
  public IList<StatsItem> Items{get;set;} 
}

public class StatsItem{
  public StatsItem(){}     

  public string UrlName{get;set;}
  public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

now just serialize this, and you have your xml document. When the time comes, deserialize it, add stuff to the Items list and serialize and save it to disk again.

There are lots of resources on google , so just search a bit for those.

Comment: can i see a code chunk that will load the file into the xmlDoc and then use the remainder of my code to append nodes, but if the file doesn't exist then load a new doc like it does now. my issue is now i lose all the history on each run cause it just over-writes the file each time and since it doesn't load and append nodes i lose all historical info.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

...

public void Append(){
    XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"yourXMLFile.xml"));
    XElement parentXElement = xmldoc.XPathSelectElement("yourRoot");
    XElement newXElement = new XElement("test", "abc");

    //append element
    parentXElement.Add(newXElement);

    xmldoc.Save(@"yourXMLFile.xml"));
  }
```

Comment: +1 for using XDocument over XmlDocument. It's a much friendlier class.