# how to insert and remove Xml document fragment between nodes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

how to insert and remove Xml document fragment between nodes.I want to add and remove xml fragment  inside particular tag.

Xml:

```
<project> 
    <ItemGroup>
       <Content Include="App_LocalResources" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
       <EmbeddedResource Include="lice.pccx" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0" />
</project>
```

I want to insert `<EmbeddedResource Include=licenses.licx />` fragment inside `<ItemGroup>`
And after that I want to remove `<EmbeddedResource Include="lice.pccx" />`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialization Xml Document Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192425/deserialization-xml-document-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xDoc = XElement.Load("FilePath");
if (xDoc == null)
   return;

var myNewElement = new XElement("ElementName"
   new XAttribute("AttributeName", value1),
   new XAttribute("AttributeName", value2)
   //And so on ...
);
xDoc.Add(myNewElement);
xDoc.Save("FilePath");
```

//

```
doc.Root.Descendants(actualNode.Parent.Name)
        .Elements(actualNode.Name)
        .Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

var xml = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
//var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString); //in case of loading from string
var liceElement = xml.XPathSelectElement("//EmbeddedResource[@Include='lice.pccx']");
liceElement.Remove();
//liceElement.Parent.Remove(); //if you would like to remove the whole 'ItemGroup' 
xml.Add(new XElement("ItemGroup",
        new XElement("EmbeddedResource",
            new XAttribute("Include", "licenses.licx"))));

xml.ToString();
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asphttp://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) you can find some useful xpath examples.